# TextMate - scroll tabs

Tags: textmate

TextMate has one irritating 'feature' that shows up when editing lot of files (within a given project). in case there is no place at tab bar for new tabs, a ">>" is shown. it simply shows a popup with rest of files. that's ok, but why when one selects a file its tab is not visible? isn't it kind of iconsistency? what is more irritating here, tabs are not shown in this case even when navigating through "Next File Tab" or "Prev File Tab".

is there any way of enabling "scrollable" tabs bar or it's just "feature, not a bug" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a byproduct of TextMate's tab-handling code (which is believe is custom-written for TextMate). I wouldn't call it a "feature" nor a "feature, not a bug", because I think it *is* a bug, just one that hasn't been fixed yet (development TextMate 1.x has been rather stagnant for the past couple of years). But I don't think there are any plugins that fix the bug and enabled a scrolling tab pane.